# Rails + bootstrap floating form

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement a "floating form" using Rails and Bootstrap, something like this:

[image: Github asignees]

[image]

Some clicks will generate AJAX requests to the rails backend.

I was thinking about doing the following:

- Define a partial/shared view that contains the form and the components.
- Use the form helper to bind rails objects and paths to it.
- Render it a .js.erb file that handles the click/hover event.

I'm lost on two parts:

- How to make the element 'float', and anchored to a specific element.
- How to make it work from a .js.erb file.

Sorry for being so broad, but I'd appreciate general guidance on how to do it.

**EDIT**: I think the solution would be using Bootstrap's dropdowns: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly you are talking about "modals" which are part of boostrap

Maybe this guide will help
[5 Steps to add remote Modals to Rails](http://www.jetthoughts.com/blog/tech/2014/08/27/5-steps-to-add-remote-modals-to-your-rails-app.html)

Comment: Thanks, that can get me started.